# Configuration or best practices wrt. automatic chaining of `setup.bash` prefix paths from `colcon build`

Tags: ros2, colcon, setup.bash

I recently found (to my great surprise) that upon issuing '`source install/setup.bash`' for my ROS 2 install (built from source), that both Gazebo Sim and ros_gz_bridge were also sourced automatically.

So I had a look at the ROS 2 `install/setup.bash` script, and indeed it mentions:

```
# This script extends the environment with the environment of other prefix
# paths which were sourced when this file was generated as well as all packages
# contained in this prefix path.
```

So probably I did the following:

- Compile and source ROS 2,
- Compile and source Gazebo Sim,
- Compile and source ros_gz_bridge,
- Compile ROS 2 again.

I wonder if many people are aware of that behavior. In any case I did not know of this automatic chaining, nor was expecting it, as:

- In above case, it is obviously undesirable that the ROS 2 `setup.bash` script would chain the Gazebo and ros_gz_bridge scripts,
- But even in other cases this can be undesired. E.g. the ros_gz_bridge obviously depends on ROS 2 and Gazebo Sim, but even then I might want to source a different ROS 2 install (e.g. with some local changes, irrelevant to ros_gz_bridge). So I don't necessarily want the ros_gz_bridge to automatically source the ROS 2 install that was sourced at build time.

Is there some documentation / configuration options / known best practices wrt. this behavior?

Or is it just mandatory to actively consider the sourced prefixes before each invocation of `colcon build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the [colcon documentation](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/environment.html#workspace-level):

- `local_setup.bash` adds only that workspace to `COLCON_PREFIX_PATH`,
- `setup.bash` adds all workspaces to `COLCON_PREFIX_PATH` that were in the `COLCON_PREFIX_PATH` at the time of build.

So my best practice is to:

- Open a separate terminal to compile,
- Source only those workspaces that are strictly needed,
- Use that terminal only to compile.

This avoids that I recompiled in a terminal where I had sourced other workspaces (e.g. PlotJuggler) and then all of these other workspaces unnecessarily end up in the `setup.bash`.